# Javascript - How to change value in form when set by function

Tags: javascript, html

I am using a HTML form that has an input from 1 till 20 and starts with 10.
So normally you can click on the side and go up till 20 or down to 1.
This worked without any problem, till i made changes to the value with a JS function.

The function is triggert by a list, and depending on the value of the list the form is updated.

As an example what is going wrong: All abilities are set to 10 at the start, if i chose Dragonborn in the list it should add +2 at STR and +1 at CHA, if i chose any other entry from the list the abilities are reset to their default value of 10.

The problem i encounter is that after the execution of the function in my example the STR is set at 12, but it is not possible to change it to any other value by hand anymore, even though the values could be any from 1 till 20. I can not click and change it to 13 or 11 or any other. It will jump back to 12 set by the function.

What i need is that everything works like i have now, but when the value is set to 12, i can change it afterwards by hand to any other value. The list am i using to update the base value is Race, and depending on the race the default value can change. But if set in my example to 12 i need to be able to change.

```
<table class="table">
                <tr>
                    <th>Ability</th>
                    <th>Score</th>
                    
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>STR: <br>Modifier:
                        <td><input type="number" value="10" min="1" max="20" id="strScore" onchange="updateModifiers()">

                            <input type="number" value="0" id="strMod"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>DEX: <br>Modifier:
                        <td><input type="number" value="10" min="1" max="20" id="dexScore" onchange="updateModifiers()">
                            <input type="number" value="0" id="dexMod"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>CON: <br>Modifier:
                        <td><input type="number" value="10" min="1" max="20" id="conScore" onchange="updateModifiers()">
                            <input type="number" value="0" id="conMod"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>INT: <br>Modifier:
                        <td><input type="number" value="10" min="1" max="20" id="intScore" onchange="updateModifiers()">
                            <input type="number" value="0" id="intMod"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>WIS: <br>Modifier:
                        <td><input type="number" value="10" min="1" max="20" id="wisScore" onchange="updateModifiers()">
                            <input type="number" value="0" id="wisMod"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>CHA: <br>Modifier:
                        <td><input type="number" value="10" min="1" max="20" id="chaScore" onchange="updateModifiers()">
                            <input type="number" value="0" id="chaMod"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>




function pRace(playerRace) {
var race = playerRace.value;
if (race == 'Dragonborn') {
    reset();
    document.getElementById("strScore").value = parseInt(document.getElementById("strScore").value) + 2;
    var strScore = document.getElementById("strScore").value;
    document.getElementById("strMod").value = Math.floor((strScore - 10) / 2);

    document.getElementById("chaScore").value = parseInt(document.getElementById("chaScore").value) + 1;
    var chaScore = document.getElementById("chaScore").value;
    document.getElementById("chaMod").value = Math.floor((chaScore - 10) / 2);


}
```

To view the workings you can visit my server:
http://raylinux.noip.me/dnd/#karakters

Comment: I can still change it by hand...

Comment: If you chose Dragonborn from Player Race, you see STR at 12. But i can not change any from the Top Scores (Not the modifiers that works).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are resetting the values during your onchange function inside the input elements and set everything again to the values reset() and pRace() sets.

Try commenting out line 49 in your updateModifiers() function which should be pRace(playerRace), there is only need to set this once the dropdown value has changed.

Comment: OK! Thanks, that was the solution. I can update it now :)